# Disappearing wireframe after clicking on green triagle 2.8+

Tags: wireframe

Today I've faced some kind of strange behaviour from blender 2.8.

I was working in *Viewport Shading* mode with *x-ray* off and *geometry>wireframe* off. Probably I had activated something because now after clicking on a **green triangle** in the scene collection window my wireframe completely disappears. The worst is that this behaviour persists absolutely everywhere. In whichever model I open that green triangle now removes wireframe and ever after restarting.

How to turn it off?!

[image: what the]

That is original *plane 1* with *Object property> Viewport display > Wireframe* unchecked however it exists.

[image: sigh]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently these wireframes were created after importing models to old blender and then copying to 2.8+.

Probably it is a bug since I can't reproduce that effect on new models.